# Copying files from my (windows) computer to a remote system over ssh

Tags: ssh, file-copy

I have some files on my laptop which I want to copy them on a remote cluster. To this end, I use PuTTy to SSH the remote cluster. Then to copy files, I use PuTTy terminal and after logging to the remote system, I write the below instruction,

```
scp -r ~/Desktop/AFU/ username@host:~/SVM
```

aiming copy all files in folder `C:Users\name\Desktop\AFU` in my laptop to a folder named `SVM` on the remote cluster.

However, it does not work and I get the error:

```
/home/username/Desktop/AFU: No such file or directory.
```

Could you please help me?
The operating system on my laptop is Windows 8.1.

Comment: I don't knwo Windows and I'm quite surprised by your source directory: `~/Desktop/AFU/`. Why not `C:\Users\name\Desktop\AFU`? Does Putty replace `~` with your home directory? Or are you using CygWin? BTW, tell us (by editing your question, not in the comments) what does not work. What is the error message?

Comment: what console are you using on the windows system? Did you confirm that the shortcut `~` is correctly resolved on windows?

Comment: When I open Putty, after entering the host name, I press OK button and then a terminal is opened. After entering my password, I connect to the remote cluster. About `~` I am not sure what it does. After running the command I get the error: `/home/username/Desktop/AFU: No such file or directory`. Also, when I write the complete address, i.e. `C:\Users\name\Desktop\AFU` I get an error which says `ssh could not resolve hostname C: Name or service not found`.

Comment: Try to `cd C:\Users\name\Desktop\AFU`  and `scp -r * username@host:~/SVM` for a start.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use scp on Windows.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you ssh to remote cluster and fire the scp command on remote cluster where ~/Desktop/AFU doesn't exist but exists on you laptop machine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `scp` command you're trying to run is not only wrong, but won't work anyway because it presumes your laptop is running a SSH server.

To do what you want, there's a much simpler way: use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php) on your laptop to connect to the remote cluster (it works similarly to PuTTY), then upload the files you want -- in your case, files from `C:Users\name\Desktop\AFU` in your laptop to `~/SVM` on the remote cluster.

Answer (score 7):

On your windows machine, use the `pscp` command that comes with Putty.

Logging into a remote system and then expecting the remote system to find files on your local system will not work (luckily!).

Answer (score 2):

From putty's homepage I believe you can download pscp which is a windows scp command application. It works as scp but from the windows side. So, something like this in a cmd windows on the Windows machine:

```
pscp -r C:/Users/<username>/Desktop/AFU username@linuxhost:~/SVM
```

Taken from the head, but something like that.